# Await results from DataContext.ExecuteQuery

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, async-await

I have a method which is being called by an MVC controller which, in turn, is being called using Ajax in a web application. It used to look like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<DepartmentViewModel> GetDepartments()
{
    DataContext db = new DataContext(ConfigurationHelper.DepartmentsConnectionString);
    string sql = "SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(DEP_CODE) AS [DepartmentCode], RTRIM(DEP_NAME) AS 
        [DepartmentName] " +
        "FROM [departmentinfo].[dbo].[Dep_School_Faculty] " +
        "WHERE [DEPARTMENT_IN_USE] = 'Y' AND [VALID] = 'Y' " +
        "ORDER BY [DepartmentName]";
     IEnumerable<DepartmentViewModel> departments = db.ExecuteQuery<DepartmentViewModel>(sql);
     return departments;
}
```

The SQL query takes a few seconds to execute, which is why it is being called by Ajax after the rest of the web page loads, so the user can be getting on with other stuff while the department list loads. This works great.

Now, though, I need to modify the query slightly and do something with the results of the data on the back end before passing it to the controller, so I updated my method to look like this:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<AcademicAreaViewModel>> AllAcademicAreas()
{
    IEnumerable<DepartmentSchoolFacultyModel> deptSchoolFaculty = await GetAllAcademicAreas();
    using (DataContext db = new DataContext(ConfigurationHelper.DepartmentsConnectionString))
    {
        string sql = "SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(DEP_CODE) AS [DepartmentCode], RTRIM(DEP_NAME) AS [DepartmentName], " +
            "RTRIM(SCHOOL_CODE) AS [SchoolCode], RTRIM(SCHOOL_NAME) AS [SchoolName], " +
            "RTRIM(FACULTY_CODE) AS [FacultyCode], RTRIM(FACULTY_NAME) AS [FacultyName] " +
            "FROM [departmentinfo].[dbo].[Dep_School_Faculty] " +
            "WHERE [DEPARTMENT_IN_USE] = 'Y' AND [VALID] = 'Y'";
        deptSchoolFaculty = db.ExecuteQuery<DepartmentSchoolFacultyModel>(sql);
    };

    IEnumerable<AcademicAreaViewModel> departments = deptSchoolFaculty
        .GroupBy(d => d.DepartmentCode)
        .Select(g => new AcademicAreaViewModel()
        {
            Name = g.First().DepartmentName,
            Code = "Department:" + g.First().DepartmentCode
        })
        .ToList();

    IEnumerable<AcademicAreaViewModel> schools = deptSchoolFaculty
        .GroupBy(d => d.SchoolCode)
        .Select(g => new AcademicAreaViewModel()
        {
            Name = g.First().SchoolName,
            Code = "School:" + g.First().SchoolCode
        })
        .ToList();

    IEnumerable<AcademicAreaViewModel> academicAreas = departments.Concat(schools);

    return academicAreas;
}
```

The problem I then hit was that the line beginning `IEnumerable<AcademicAreaViewModel> departments = deptSchoolFaculty` was throwing a null exception error because the `deptSchoolFaculty` variable hadn't yet been populated with data.

So, I thought, here's a typical use case for asynchronous programming, which just happens to my nemesis (no matter how much I read on the subject or implement it, it just never "clicks" in my head).

I refactored my code like this:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<AcademicAreaViewModel>> AllAcademicAreasAsync()
{
    IEnumerable<DepartmentSchoolFacultyModel> deptSchoolFaculty = await GetAllAcademicAreasAsync();

    IEnumerable<AcademicAreaViewModel> departments = deptSchoolFaculty
        .GroupBy(d => d.DepartmentCode)
        .Select(g => new AcademicAreaViewModel()
        {
            Name = g.First().DepartmentName,
            Code = "Department:" + g.First().DepartmentCode
        })
        .ToList();

    IEnumerable<AcademicAreaViewModel> schools = deptSchoolFaculty
        .GroupBy(d => d.SchoolCode)
        .Select(g => new AcademicAreaViewModel()
        {
            Name = g.First().SchoolName,
            Code = "School:" + g.First().SchoolCode
        })
        .ToList();

    IEnumerable<AcademicAreaViewModel> academicAreas = departments.Concat(schools);

    return academicAreas;
}

private static Task<IEnumerable<DepartmentSchoolFacultyModel>> GetAllAcademicAreasAsync()
{ 
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        IEnumerable<DepartmentSchoolFacultyModel> deptSchoolFaculty = new List<DepartmentSchoolFacultyModel>();
        using (DataContext db = new DataContext(ConfigurationHelper.DepartmentsConnectionString))
        {
            string sql = "SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(DEP_CODE) AS [DepartmentCode], RTRIM(DEP_NAME) AS [DepartmentName] " +
                "FROM [departmentinfo].[dbo].[Dep_School_Faculty] " +
                "WHERE [DEPARTMENT_IN_USE] = 'Y' AND [VALID] = 'Y' " +
                "ORDER BY [DepartmentName]";
            
            return db.ExecuteQuery<DepartmentSchoolFacultyModel>(sql);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Unfortunately, the same line throws the same null exception error, even though I'm using the `await` keyword to, I hoped, wait for the result of the SQL query before proceeding.

First of all, I don't understand why, in the original version of my code, the method seemed to wait for the SQL query to be complete before returning results (since results were always returned to my page), but now that I'm trying to work with the results in the same method it doesn't.

Secondly, whilst I suspect that the answer to my problem may be to use one of the [asynchronous data methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/asynchronous-programming?view=sql-server-ver15) instead of `DataContext.ExecuteQuery`, I would like to understand why what I've written doesn't work. Also, I much prefer the conciseness of `ExecuteQuery` for writing the results of the sql query straight into a C# model in one line.

Comment: Question: why SQL? This can be easily converted to LINQ.

Comment: Fair question. This database isn't the main database for my application (for which I am using EF), I only call it for this one thing, so it seemed overkill to create an additional ADO data model and so on.

Comment: Which ORM do you use?

Comment: Well I'm not using any ORM for this, it's just a single call to a database. I use EF for my main application's database but that isn't relevant to this question.

Comment: If `db.ExecuteQuery<DepartmentSchoolFacultyModel>(sql)` returns `IEnumerable`, you have to call .`ToList()` inside using, because you dispose `DataContext` and enumeration cannot finish.

Comment: That seems to have done it, thanks!

Comment: As a side note you are using `Task.Run` in order to [expose an asynchronous wrapper for a synchronous method](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/), and you are doing so in a web application. Now wait for Stephen Cleary to come and educate you about why [this is a bad idea](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have problem with disposing `DataContext` before finishing enumeration of the result. It can be fixed by adding `.ToList()` call or extending scope for `using`.

```cs
deptSchoolFaculty = db.ExecuteQuery<DepartmentSchoolFacultyModel>(sql).ToList();
```